# Limit file type upload video

Tags: php

how do I add that only mp4 is accepted?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    move_uploaded_file($temp,"uploaded/".$name);
    $url = "/uploaded/$name";

    $db->query("INSERT INTO `videos` VALUES ('','$name','$url')");

    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE name = '".$name."'");
    $row = $query->fetch_assoc();
    echo "<center>Your upload is created <a href='watch.php?id=".$row['id']. "' target='blank_'>CLICK</a></center>";
}
?>
```

Can you repost the php with right php script

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is **NOT** a code writing service. We are always glad to help and support new coders *but you need to help yourself first. :-)* You are expected to try to write the code yourself. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There doesn't seem to have been much effort / research put into this. Googling "allow certain file types when uploading videos php", helped me find a duplicate for this. That should have been a question that you may have already asked yourself but didn't Google "it".

Answer (score 0):

This is also one way.

```
$filetype = $_FILES['file']['type'];
if ($filetype != 'video/mp4') {
    exit('Stop, wrong file!);
}
```

Comment: It's not. The mime type is sent by the client and can be spoofed.